# How to use RunAs Cmd to Launch Explorer, Windows 8

Tags: windows, cmd, explorer, runas

any idea why this is not working?

```
runas.exe /user:Administrator "cmd /c explorer"
```

it returns:

> Windows cannot find the specified file. You may not have appropriate
>   permissions.

the following works by itself:

```
cmd /c explorer
```

thx!

Comment: Is the Administrator user locked? If so, is there a password set for the user? By default (on my Win7 installation) that is not the case.

Comment: What does "locked" mean? It's enabled and I gave a password.

Comment: partially resolved-- i logged into the admin desktop, which i'd not done before, and ran explorer. then, logged back into the restricted user account, and above command successfully launched. However, the explorer that opened does not have access to the admin user-folder, so it appearts that it's not really running as admin...? will try adding /env, /profile, or /noprofile switches.

Comment: update, above switches did not help. I've read this may require a group policy edit, but it appears that group policy editor is not available on Win 8.

Comment: Also, seems if i right-click on  Windows/explorer.exe and click "run as administrator", it too does not have access to the admin folder. So this looks like it's not an issue with commandline "runas", it's an issue with explorer.exe. I checked explorer.exe security properties: the owner is "trusted installer" and Administrators group has full control.

Answer (score 3):

Answer found here
http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-run-explorer-as-administrator-on-windows-8-1-windows-8-and-windows-7/

"Microsoft does not allow running Explorer as administrator in Windows 8.1/8 (and in Windows 7 too). The solution to run Explorer elevated...

1-  take ownership of registry key below.

- Right-click, Permissions, Advanced, Owner Change
- or, Use Winaero's RegOwnershipEx application, which allows you to take ownership of registry keys

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppID{CDCBCFCA-3CDC-436f-A4E2-0E02075250C2}

2- rename or delete the value named 'RunAs'.

3- now Restore Ownership **(this failed for me done manually-- i could not re-add TrustedInstaller --user not found).**

4- at this point, you will be able to run explorer as admin

5- this process does not cleanly exit when you close the Explorer window! You must remember to terminate it every time you elevate Explorer after you are done working in the Explorer window.

Alternate solution: use Winaero's ELE.exe app to start any program as administrator from the command line.

Comment: The name for the TrustedInstaller-user is "NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller"

Answer (score 1):

Usually one wants to run as an Administrator to edit a file, or get permissions to delete a file:

To get to the permissions on a file you can right click on it and select Properties. Then select Security. You will see this dialog:

[image: File Security Dialog]

Then Click on Edit and change the permissions for the relevant user (e.g Mike).
You need to have admin privileges to do this, which can be set via User Account Control.

The File Permissions window looks like this:

[image: Permissions Dialog]

Edit as required.

I have admin rights but Windows 8.1 still protects some system files (such as the Android studio.exe.vmoptions) and I used the above method to give me write access to the file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You could always open a dos prompt as Administrator then go to the directory in question then do a Explorer . then it will open the location in question as the elevated user.

Comment: Seems reasonable, but fails.

Comment: I tried this before coming here, but Explorer does not open as an admin from an Admin command line. I tried doing it in several different ways, but each Explorer instance opened still only had standard privileges.

To get to the Device Manager as Admin, I just had to enter "mmc devmgmt.msc" from an admin command line.